# Save player data in Unity 3D

Tags: unity

I've started to design a commercial Client/Server game in Unity and I need server-side saves players data for later analysis and web consultation (like battle.net). Is there a best practice to achieve this? Can I use MongoDb for a commercial game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only answer to your first question (as I don't have a clue about MongoDB + commercial game).

Unity3D has a set of classes to communicate through HTTP. They are not perfect but they exists and (usually) work.

Have a look at [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class, to set up a connection, and also at [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) to send requests and data to your server using HTTP.

Once your game will be able to read and write data via HTTP you will have to write the server side logic to save this data into your database.

Note that it's also possible to communicate through C# classes such as [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), if you need to use commands not allowed by Unity `WWW`, such as `PUT`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It can be the right direction! Server can call a WebApi project throught http calls but what about performance?

Comment: Well about performance,as for local ones, online data saves have to be done during not too critical game phases. So performances will really depend on you. Note that it's better to use www in a coroutine to not lock the game execution. Normally performance of your game won't be affected.